# Regular monomorphisms and embeddings

Tags: category-theory

Assume that we have a *construct* **A** in a sense that it is a *concrete category* over **Set**. I’m trying to verify the fact that every regular monomorphism in such construct which has a free object over a nonempty set must be an embedding.

If we will suppose that $A \overset {m} \longrightarrow B$ is an equalizer of a pair of morphisms $(u,v)$, and let $g:|C|\longrightarrow |A|$ be an **Set**-morphism such that $m\circ g$ is an **A**-morphism. Then since $u\circ (m\circ g)=v\circ (m\circ g)$, there exists an **A**-morphism $k:C\longrightarrow A$ with $m\circ g=m\circ k$. Then I have to prove that $k=g$ to say that $m$ is initial.

And on the second step I have to prove that $|A| \overset {m} \longrightarrow |B|$ is monomorphic.

So if such morphism $A\overset {m} \longrightarrow B$ both initial and has a monomorphic underlying **Set**-morphism then it is an embedding.

Could someone give some ideas to finish the proof? Or are there other ways to establish this fact?

Comment: What do you mean by "embedding"?

Comment: @ArnaudD., I’ve edited the post and added this definition to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, all you need is to prove is that the function underlying $m$ is injective; indeed, if this is the case then $m\circ g=m\circ k$ will imply $g=k$ in $\mathbf{Set}$.

So how to prove that $m$ is injective in $\mathbf{Set}$? Let us take $a_1,a_2\in |A|$ such that $m(a_1)=m(a_2)$. Let $X\neq \emptyset$ be a set for which there exists a free object $F(X)$ in $\mathbf{A}$, with a canonical function $\eta:X\to |F(X)|$. Let us define two constant functions $w_i:X\to |A|:x\mapsto a_i$ ($i=1,2$); note that $m\circ w_1=m\circ w_2$. Then by the universal property of $F(X)$, there exists $\mathbf{A}$-morphisms $\varphi_i:F(X)\to A$ whose underlying functions satisfy $\varphi_i(\eta(x))=w_i(x)=a_i$ for all $x\in X$. Now notice that $m\circ \varphi_i$ are two $\mathbf{A}$-morphisms, and
$$(m\circ \varphi_1)(\eta(x))=m(a_1)=m(a_2)=(m\circ \varphi_2)(\eta(x))$$
for all $x\in X$, thus by the universal property, we have $m\circ \varphi_1=m\circ \varphi_2$ in $\mathbf{A}$. Since $m$ is a monomorphism in $\mathbf{A}$ (as an equalizer), we must have $\varphi_1=\varphi_2$, which implies that $a_1=a_2$.